# How to reuse Request.getParameter("paramName") in other place in doGet servlet

Tags: java, servlets, servletcontextlistener, servlet-listeners

I have `doGet` and `doPost` methods in a servlet and I have `Request.getParameter("paramName")` in both of them 
I want to use `Request.getParameter("paramName")` out of `doGet` in another place in my code for example:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest Request, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();        
        pw.print("Param is "+  Request.getParameter("paramName"));
    }

  PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
  out.write( Request.getParameter("paramName"));
```

Could it be possible to achieve this?

Comment: Please fix the code sample, it looks like you have 2 lines outside of a function now, but that wouldn't even compile.

Comment: 2 lines are just an example 
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException           
    {  
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();        
          
        pw.print("Param is "+  req.getParameter("paramName"));
    }

 String x = nb.predict(req.getParameter("paramName"));
        if (!x.equals(trainingFiles.put("ok", NB.class.getResource("/datasets/training.ntraffic.nt.txt")).toString())) 
        {
        res.sendRedirect("WoringPage");
        }
        else 
        { 
        }

Answer (score 0):

You can either pass request to the method, or pull the value into a variable and pass that to the method.

```
String data = Request.getParameter("paramName");
doSomethingWithData(data);

private void doSomethingWithData(String data){
    System.out.println(data);
}
```

Comment: please give an example